# How do i factory reset my laptop?

Tags: reset

I received a laptop that runs Ubuntu from a friend who passed away. I dont have any login for them and am not able to change any settings. Pmeaae help me factory reset

Comment: Sorry to hear about your friend's passing. I think will need to reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: Two ways of doing it.  The easiest one is to download a newer version of Ubuntu do a install of it.  Instructions and download ISOs are at Ubuntu.com.  Second way requires an Ubuntu  ISO also, burned to USB and then googling how to change forgotten password.  If you know any specs of computer we can give some advice on what Ubuntu version/desktop would work well.  Some versions have lighter requirements.

Comment: If there's any data which should be preserved on that system, you can do that with an Ubuntu LiveUSB drive. Please let us know if you need to do that; otherwise, please let us know the make and model part number of the PC, which is obtained from the serial number sticker.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

- boot the computer to the GRUB menu
- choose the 2nd item on the list... "Additional Options"
- choose "Recovery Mode"
- choose "Root Access"
- if it doesn't ask for a password, just hit the ENTER key
- if it does ask for a password, try "root" or "admin"
- you should be at the # prompt
- type `ls -al /home`
- note the previous owners name... let's say it's "joe"
- type `sudo passwd joe`
- type a new password twice
- type `reboot`
- at the Ubuntu login screen, select "joe"
- enter the new password that you created earlier
- go to User settings
- create a new ADMIN account for yourself
- log out
- log into your own account

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the password you are wasting your time resting the root password...and you don't have to remember the login password ...just install another ubuntu or any linux distribution ....

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a bootable USB of Ubuntu using the tutorial [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview). After that, you can plug the USB drive in and enter the computer's BIOS before the operating system loads (normally the key to do this is <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, or <kbd>DELETE</kbd> as the computer is booting up). You can select boot from USB and begin a new install on the computer.